# Analysis services processing task editor window disappears when adding object

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, etl, ssas-tabular

I'm using VS 2017 Community on Windows 10 and trying to create a SSIS project to ETL data from a SSAS tabular model into a SQL server database. I've added an Analysis Services Processing Task and have setup a connection for it. When I click Add in this window, it just disappears without any error(s):

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: That's bad.  Have you tried restarting VS or reinstalling the SSAS extension?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz Tried restarting VS with no luck, but hadn't tried reinstalling SSAS extension. Will test it tomorrow.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz I removed SSIS and SSAS extensions from within VS and re-added them using SSDT setup (Modify option). But it changed nothing and behavior is still the same.

Comment: I know this is not a solution, but I replaced this task with a mixture of OLE DB data source and MDX queries. At least it works and brings data to local SQL Server.

Comment: I typically use the Analysis Services Execute DDL task which let's you call xmla scripts.  That might be what you meant anyway.  Glad you found a work around.